# How to extract rows with linq from JArray Groupby

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, json.net

I have applied GroupBy on columns of JArray and looping through all grouped list and from each group trying to get rows where "sectionGroup" column value is null. But when I try with Linq, it's returning Boolean list. I have never worked with JArray before.

```
public Task<JArray> JLogData(JArray jArray)
        {
            var groupData = jArray.GroupBy(g => new { modelName = g["modelName"], nlpModelVersion = g["nlpModelVersion"], docId = g["docId"] });
            foreach (var item in groupData)
            {
                // This is returning Boolean list. and I am trying go get list
                var itemSectionGroup = item.Select(x => x["sectionGroup"] == null);
                var itemSectionGroupNull = item.Select(x => x["sectionGroup"] != null);
            }
        }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share some sample input and output JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the rows where the `sectionGroup` column value is null, you should use the `Where` method instead of `Select`, and only then **filter** the elements.

```
var itemSectionGroupNull = item.Where(x => x["sectionGroup"] == null).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks.. yes I did tried but I have sectionGroup as null in JArray and I am not getting anything in result list. but when I do Not equal (!=) its giving me result. so Is there a different way to check null ?

Comment: Maybe `x => x["sectionGroup"] == JValue.Null` ?

Comment: `item.Select(x => x["sectionGroup"].IsNullOrEmpty()).ToList()` IsNullOrEmpty() we can achieve. but I dont see anything for checking not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse("your json string here");
    
    // Group the items in the JArray by a specific property
    var groupedItems = jsonArray.GroupBy(x => (string)x["PropertyName"]);
    
    // Extract the rows from the grouped items
    var extractedRows = groupedItems.SelectMany(group =>
    {
        // Select the rows from the current group
        var rows = group.Select(x => new
        {
            Property1 = (string)x["Property1"],
            Property2 = (string)x["Property2"],
            // add other properties as needed
        });
        
        // Return the rows as an IEnumerable
        return rows;
    });
    
    // Use the extracted rows as needed
    foreach (var row in extractedRows)
    {
        // Do something with the row
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).